# Removing trailing zero's from plot created by sygnif

Tags: r

I have the problem following. Let's say I run the code :

```
plot(1:10,yaxt='n')
axis(2,signif(seq(1,10,9/4),2))
```

signif(...,2) means that I want to have on y axis numbers which has 'length of two' (it means that are created by two numbers)

[image]

and now I have a question, is there any possibility to delete 0 in 10.0 at the top ? I mean instead of having 10.0 I want to have 10 (which is also a number created by two numbers)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formating over labels:

```
#Plot
plot(1:10,yaxt='n')
#Label
x <- trimws(format(signif(seq(1,10,9/4),2),nsmall = 1))
x <- ifelse(nchar(x)>3,signif(as.numeric(x),1),x)
#Axis
axis(2,signif(seq(1,10,9/4),2),labels = x)
```

[image]